# getting node env variables in typescript

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

I'm new to typescript and can't seem to access my process.env variables in my typescript pages. It seems it's a scope issue, but that makes no sense.

I get my environment variables from a yaml file and the attach them to the running process.

```
module.exports = function() {
   const YAML = require('yamljs');
    const envVars = YAML.load('env.yml')[process.env.NODE_ENV];
    Object.keys(envVars).forEach(v => {
        console.log('vars', v);
        process.env[v] = envVars[v];
    });
};
```

I then run my typescript in npm with

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=test node -e \"require('./setup-env')()\" && jasmine-ts **/*.spec.ts
```

I can see the console for each var in the `loadYmlEnv` but when I try to console log the vars from my typescript files, they are all undefined. I can spit out the entire `process.env` and the env vars I need are not there.... strange

Comment: Do you run your typescript files in another process?  https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env It is possible to modify this object, but such modifications will not be reflected outside the Node.js process.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I thought they were run in a single thread, but apparently not. I've included the set-up as part of my tests, but it isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross-env NODE_ENV=test node -e \"require('./setup-env')()\" && jasmine-ts **/*.spec.ts

This creates a process with NODE_ENV set to test

Then you create a different process that requires 'setup-env' and then that process exits

Then you run jasmine-ts that only have NODE_ENV=test set up